I have two samples size. One is 135 the other 15. Can I use Chi-square for analysis
I am conducting a survey about awareness. I have two variable. One is student sample size 150 and the other teachers sample size 15 using questionnaire on 4 point likert scale. Can I use Chi-square? For analysis
